# Monitoring MS Dynamics 365 with Extended Events

Tags: profiler, extended-events, microsoft-dynamics

I know that SQL Server and Azure SQL support "Extended Events" as a means of profiling execution.  I also know that MS Dynamics 365 is built with Azure SQL.  What I'd like to accomplish is creating and managing XEvents for MS Dynamics 365 (i.e on its underlying Azure SQL DB).  Presumably this means I'd be storing the telemetry data into Azure BLOB storage.

Is it possible to profile the MS Dynamics 365 CRM, or is it so deeply "managed"...that such instrumentation isn't possible?  And if it isn't possible, are there any particular alternatives?  My intent is to capture a cross-section of what kinds of queries/updates are being performed against the DB...and in what quantities for a typical daily client work-load.

A key motivation for this is to serve as an input for capacity planning for the creation of a custom "operational data store", into which a breadth of applications will subsequently depend on for similar data.

Comment: Unless you plan on trying to fix Microsoft's code, or write your own code to supplement the same calls, what is your goal in profiling their ERP system?

Comment: @J.D. I've updated the question to explain the motivation.  I am tasked to build a central operational data store which can withstand the same load and at least similar types of queries.  I can't read through Dynamics code, but conceptually I can look at XEvents to create a picture.

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, I meant their CRM system. No offense, sounds a little silly of a task / approach to capacity planning for your own database and apps for a few reasons: 1. As much as Microsoft is good at what they do, they have a lot of poorly architected and implemented code under their ERP & CRM systems (some of it being legacy stuff they're just stuck supporting). 2. There are so many variables with capacity planning and performance tuning that something as simple as having an extra space at the end of one of your queries could end up with a different performance outcome than Microsoft's.